# How to not add a delay to a function

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am new to JavaScript and following this [tutorial](http://www.zekechan.net/asteroids-html5-game-tutorial-5/) I have made the game work perfectly and it goes up to the part of were the the level changes when you destroy all the objects. However as I am learning I am trying to figure out how to make it so that it changes level without a delay.

The main part of the bit which switches level is :

```
if (!this.rockmodel.countLiving()) {
    Asteroid.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * gameWindow.delayToStartLevel, this.levelIncrease, this);
}
```

However if I take out the `delayToStartLevel` bit, it does not switch level. So I tried to make it looks like this:

```
Asteroid.time.events.add(this.levelIncrease, this);
```

But the next level does not show at all. Not sure if I am being an idiot etc, but any help on this matter would be great.

Again just to make some sense, it works fine with the delay, I want to get rid of that function completely but its not working at all.

Thanks.

Comment: replace `gameWindow.delayToStartLevel` with 0 (zero) or replace everything before the first comma with 0.

Comment: @RST Worked thanks so much xx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `time.events.add` will add an event to the Phaser game object. In other words it will fire the given function after X milliseconds.

If you do not want a delay then you can just call the function directly, instead of postponing the function call. Something like this:

```
if (!this.rockmodel.countLiving()) {
    this.levelIncrease();
}
```